# Multiple-passes SSAO border artifact

Tags: webgl, blending, ssao

I am playing with multiple passes in WebGL to apply some visual enhancements to my renders.

I am ping-ponging two textures  (taken from here: [WebGL Image Processing Continued](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html)), and this is basically my workflow:

1. draw the geometry and store the depth vales in a texture buffer
2. apply the SSAO pass (based on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rabbid76/92zmsv6m/) from [Rabbid76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577765/rabbid76))
3. at the end, I am rendering the texture to the screen

Now, I am not able to understand why there is a black border around some parts of the final image.
I tried to fine adjust some SSAO parameters, but I wasn't able to get rid from that artifact, so, just guessing, i believe now that this black border is due a wrong blending setup of my texture buffers.

This is actually the code in the depth pass:

```
gl.disable(gl.BLEND);
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.depthMask(true);
... drawings
```

I tried also this way:

```
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendEquation(gl.FUNC_ADD);
gl.blendFunc(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

...but is not leading me to any result.

In the picture below, this artifact is clearly to see as a thin black line around the stanford dragon:

[image: SSAO]

As I am completely lost with this issue, can someone point me to the right direction?

My question: I need to draw a geometry with transparent background - which is the correct blending mode for that, when rendering to a back buffer and ping-ponging two textures to apply multiple effects?

Comment: There can be so many things going wrong. First, understand what SSAO is for: Modulate ambient light. If the border is on the background which does not get shaded, it's of no consequence. Maybe your background is too far away?

Comment: @starmole: many THX for your time, I don't know yet if i will blend the ssao texture into the final image or apply the SSAO to the ambient light, so I am actually experimenting. I am lost because i need high frequency detail and I am not able to achieve good results within the blur pass..For the issue in the question, actually I ended up by blending the alpha in the fragment shader.

Comment: SSAO is low frequency by nature. A lot of people add extra AO maps to models for finer details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the posterity, I was using:

```
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

so i changed the pack/unpack functions as follows:

```
vec4 PackDepth32_0(float depth) {
    const vec4 bit_shift = vec4(255.0 * 255.0 * 255.0, 255.0 * 255.0, 255.0, 1.0);
    const vec4 bit_mask = vec4(0.0, 1.0 / 255.0, 1.0 / 255.0, 1.0 / 255.0);
    vec4 res = fract(depth * bit_shift);
    res -= res.xxyz * bit_mask;
    return res;
}
float UnpackDepth32_0(vec4 color) {
    const vec4 bit_shift = vec4(1.0 / (255.0 * 255.0 * 255.0), 1.0 / (255.0 * 255.0), 1.0 / 255.0, 1.0);
    return dot(color, bit_shift);
}
```

which solves my problem.